# I need to give NAs in a column a value based on value in another column

Tags: r, na

My question above doesn't fully explain the issue I am facing. 
Just a disclaimer - I am very, very new with R, and I am teaching myself (or rather Google is teaching me) so apologies if my questions are really naive. 
I have a household level data which I converted to individual level. The long and the short of it is that created lots of NAs. The data looks something like this:

[snapshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpmzk.jpg)

I want the households with the same code to have the same province and region, not NA. The data is like this because there is more than one individual in one household (obviously). The actual data is much bigger than this.

Would appreciate any help! I can give more info as required.

Best,
Asma

Comment: You should add data itself in the question instead of a snapshot.  Run `head(dataframe_object, 10)` and copy the output here.

Comment: Or better yet: `dput(head(dataframe, 10))`

Comment: It seems to me that the question is mislabeled.  The NAs need to be replaced by data within each column, not from another column, right?

Comment: Yes - the question could be better labeled - I'll fix that, thanks! Will also add the actual data for others who might find this useful

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
dataframe$Z <- ifelse(is.na(dataframe$X), dataframe$Y, dataframe$X)
```

Where `dataframe` is the data-frame in question; `X` is the column containing some `NA` values; `Y` is the column to fall-back to; and `Z` is the column containing the coalesced result

Comment: I don't think this gives the answer the OP is looking for.  Despite how the question is labeled, I think they need the values that replace the `NA`s to be from the same column but a different row--not from the a different column.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this looping method:

```
# in initialize a new data frame
data2 = NULL
codes = unique(data$hhcode)

for(i in 1:length(codes)){
  # subset data by hhcode
  data1 = data[data$hhcode == codes[i],]

  # as long as you only have one unique region per code
  # you can pull out the unique factor and then set all
  # region variable for a single code
  region = data1$region[is.na(data1$region) == F]
  data1$region = region

  # do the same for province
  province = data1$province[is.na(data1$province ) == F]
  data1$province = province 

  #bind data to a new data frame
  data2 = rbind(data2,data1)
}

head(data2)
data2[1:30,]
```

Comment: I think this answer also gives what the OP was looking for.  You could also use `!is.na()` rather than `is.na() == F`.  The last part should be `data2[1:15,]` or just `data2` in order to avoid printing unnecessary `NA`s.  Also, `rbind()` at the end could get very slow if the dataset is large.

Answer (score 1):

So as a rooky you could use a simple for loop. Later on better use sthg from apply().

Step 1)
Create the dataset.
"sdgfsdh" is right the usage of dput(head(dataframe, 10)) by the OP would have been better. However for convenience for a R-Rooky.
Recreate the dataset:

```
df = data.frame(hhcode = c(rep(101010101, 5), rep(101010102, 5), rep(101010103, 5)),
                province = c(rep(c(rep(NA, 4), "punjab"), 2), c(rep(NA, 4), "sindh")), 
                region = rep(c(rep(NA, 4), "urban"), 3))
```

2)
Replace the NA´s.

For each row we want to replace the second and third column. Or with other words: We want to replace every column, except for the first one. We can exclude columns if we write a minus in front of the index: df[, -1]. 
Now we want to replace the NAs by the rows a) that do not obtain NAs for "region" and "province", but b) share the same hhcode value.

a) How do we identify the rows, that do not obtain NAs? Use na.omit(df). 
b) Lets say the df$hhcode is stored in a variable called hhcode, then we want the rows where df$hhcode is equal to hhcode --> df$hhcode == hcode. (note that which() gives us the index of the "TRUE" cases in  df$hhcode == hcode.

Finally, we want to repeat that for every unique hhcode that exists. The important words in this sentence are: "for" and "unique".
In your dataset I can identify groups that share the same "hhcode". The hhcode we can access by df$hhcode. To get all unique hhcode we use unique(df$hhcode).
So we loop through every element in unique(df$hhcode) and replace the NAs =).

```
for(hhcode in unique(df$hhcode)){
  df[which(df$hhcode == hhcode), -1] = na.omit(df)[na.omit(df)$hhcode == hhcode, -1]
}
df
```

Comment: I think this answer gives what the OP was looking for.  I think they might appreciate an explanation about what the code is doing.

Comment: Good question. I will remove this answer if the OP clarifies it that way.

Comment: Just a question - if I have other columns that I need to keep as is, how will that be incorporate into this?

Comment: Hi usmoi, check the code box at the end of my post. Inside the for loop - on the left side of the equal sign it reads: "df[which(df$hhcode == hhcode), -1] ". As I wrote in the text "We can exclude columns if we write a minus in front of the index: df[, -1]." So lets assume you have a forth column, you do not want to change --> df[, c(-1, -4)]. Or in your example - inside the for loop, write: df[which(df$hhcode == hhcode), c(-1, -4)] = na.omit(df)[na.omit(df)$hhcode == hhcode, c(-1, -4)]. If that answers your question feel free to mark the post above as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = data.frame(hhcode = c(rep(101010101, 5), rep(101010102, 5), rep(101010103, 5)),
                province = c(rep(c(rep(NA, 4), "punjab"), 2), c(rep(NA, 4), "sindh")), 
                region = rep(c(rep(NA, 4), "urban"), 3))
```

First you generate a data.frame df_complete123 consisting only of complete cases in the first three columns (no NAs)

```
df_complete123 <- df[!is.na(df$province) & !is.na(df$region),]
```

It will look like this

```
hhcode      province  region
101010101   punjab    urban
101010102   punjab    urban
101010103   sindh     urban
```

Next you will use this as some kind of look-up table. First

```
indices <- match(df$hhcode, df_complete123$hhcode)
```

which will give you this

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

This means that the entries of the first column (hhcode) in `df` are found in the 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ... -th row in df_complete123.

You use this to replace the values in 2nd and 3rd columns in df by those of df_complete123:

```
df$province <- df_complete123$province[indices]
df$region <- df_complete123$region[indices]
```

This results in

```
     hhcode province region
1  101010101   punjab  urban
2  101010101   punjab  urban
3  101010101   punjab  urban
4  101010101   punjab  urban
5  101010101   punjab  urban
6  101010102   punjab  urban
7  101010102   punjab  urban
8  101010102   punjab  urban
9  101010102   punjab  urban
10 101010102   punjab  urban
11 101010103    sindh  urban
12 101010103    sindh  urban
13 101010103    sindh  urban
14 101010103    sindh  urban
15 101010103    sindh  urban
```

Good Luck!

Comment: This works too - thanks! This has the added advantage that I can use it for datasets with additional columns and they'll remain unchanged (which is what I wanted).